# What does 'gotcha' mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does 'gotcha' mean? When would you use it?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

*Gotcha* actually has several meanings. All of them can be derived from the phrase of which this is a phonetic spelling, namely "[I have] got you".

- Literally, from the sense of *got* = "caught, obtained", it means "I've caught you". As in, you were falling, and I caught you, or you were running, and I grabbed you.
- It's a short step from the benign type of *caught* to the red-handed type of *caught*. Thus, *gotcha* is often used when you witness someone doing something naughty.
- Again, it's a short step from *I-caught-you-doing-something-you-oughtn't* to *Surprise! I tricked you!* This sense of *gotcha* is used when someone falls for a practical joke, for example.
- A somewhat-natural progression from the "I tricked you" meaning is *gotcha* used as a noun: this is a feature of a system (e.g. a programming language) which trips you up or catches you off-guard.
- And finally, from the figurative sense of *got* = "understood", *gotcha* can be used to mean "Aha, I see now" or "I understand".

Comment: +1 Well, that's certainly the most comprehensive answer.

Comment: +1 For including the noun sense, which is the first thing I think of.

Comment: +1 and a link to [all this stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha), including that, erm, *weird* [arcade game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_%28arcade_game%29).

Comment: Today I learned that the meaning of gotcha is very rarely the meaning I most often associate it with - i.e. to have understood something...

Answer (score 11):

Following from Jasper Loy's statement.

It is short for *"Got you!"*, itself having the subject implied *"I have got you."*.

It regularly means, at least in the UK, *"I understand [what you mean]"*.

> A: You turn left, then right, go
> straight on and it is on your left.
>
> B: Gotcha!

and

> A: They'll never know who did it... *<manic laughter>*
>
> B: Gotcha! You little tyke!

Comment: It regularly means, at least in the UK, "I understand [what you mean]". - True in the US as well

Comment: @Adam Thanks for that, I thought it did in the US, but was unsure.

Answer (score 7):

It is short for *got you*.

We use it when we have caught somebody doing something or when we have tricked somebody. In fact, there was a comedy show called *Gotcha!*

Answer (score 5):

Gotcha

1. 'Got you' like caught you doing something you should be doing.
2. In programming a variable of step not considered that causes an error.

Comment: +1 That was a meaning I forgot to mention, your second point.  A "gotcha" can be a pitfall, trap or potential issue in an environment or situation (or a programming language).  A common phrase is *"are there any gotchas?"*, asking if their are any potential issues that will catch you out if unaware of their presence.

Answer (score 1):

It can also mean literally "I have got you." If I catch someone before they fall, I could say "Gotcha!"